# VBA Excel iterate on multiple range

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am writing the code in repittative fashion but I want to now how can I use loop on multiple range to achieve the same outcome.

I am getting error if I put two ranges in For Each.

```
Sub test_Click()

If (Range("C3").Value <> Range("C6").Value) Then
    Range("B3").Value = 5

End If

If (Range("D3").Value <> Range("D6").Value) Then
    Range("C3").Value = 5

End If


If (Range("E3").Value <> Range("E6").Value) Then
    Range("D3").Value = 5

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why you should be getting an error in your `For Each` statement.  (But, then again, I don't understand what you mean by "if I put two ranges in For Each".)

```
Sub test_Click()
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel in Range("C3:E3").Cells
        If cel.Value <> cel.Offset(3, 0).Value Then
            cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = 5
        End If
    Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: It's good that you added `Range("C3:E3").Cells`, otherwise Excel wouldn't know how to loop through the `Cells` ;) JK

Comment: @ShaiRado I have gotten into the habit of adding `.Cells` to stop me from accidentally forgetting to include it when I do something like `For Each cel in Rows("1:10")` (where it defaults to processing a `Row` at a time instead of a cell at a time).  So there is **some** method to my madness! :D

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with the offset command in a for loop

```
For i = 0 To 3
    If (Range("C3").Offset(0, i).Value <> Range("C6").Offset(0, i).Value) Then
        Range("B3").Offset(0, i).Value = 5 
    End If
Next
```